# Custom styling in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 5

```
<p class="reverse-text">Blahbuhblah</p>

p.reverse-text {
  color: white;
}
```

This isn't working. Other custom styles I have added work fine. Trying to change color of sidebar paragraph text.

Comment: Well then it’s most likely a problem with selector specificity. Go use your browser’s developer tools to find out what rule the element is getting its color from.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add the css class above the tag

```
 <style>
p.reverse-text {
  color: white !important;
}
</style>
 <p class="reverse-text">Blahbuhblah</p>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Is this something that I have to do in general with Foundation? I thought I could just add to my custom.css file. What makes this different?

Comment: First its directly above the P tag so css order is from top to bottom if you have class p.reverse-text in line 10 of css file that says color is black and you have another p.reverse-text in line 100 that says color is red the final color will be red. and then there is the !important attribute that takes over all other class element values. you can add this class without <styel> </style> tags to your css file at the very bottom. 
and i am not sure who voted this down if this is a correct answer please vote up and mark it correct.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried using !important, but it didn't work. Now that I am trying it again-- it works. Anyway, thanks again. I marked it as correct, but I don't have any reputation to upvote it.

Comment: @BOB3000 that's all right probably there were other classes that were positioned lower than the class you were modifying